# Confused with HoldForm in Postfix notation

Tags: evaluation, hold

Why does the following code produce different result? In my mental model, they should be the same.

```
Table[With[{x = i^k}, HoldForm[x]], {k, 1, 5}]
With[{x = i^k}, HoldForm[x]] // Table[#, {k, 1, 5}] &
```

Output:

```
{i,i^2,i^3,i^4,i^5}
{i^k,i^k,i^k,i^k,i^k}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is because in the second case

```
With[{x = i^k}, HoldForm[x]] // Table[#, {k, 1, 5}] &
```

The `With` expression is evaluated (giving `HoldForm[i^k]`) before it is substituted inside the placeholder in `Table`. To prevent thise pre-evaluation wrap it around `Unevaluated` as follows:

```
Unevaluated[With[{x = i^k}, HoldForm[x]]] // Table[#, {k, 1, 5}] &
```

Which gives as before:

> `{i, i^2, i^3, i^4, i^5}`

Comment: What is the difference between `Unevaluated` and `HoldForm`? They seem to be similar intuitively.

Comment: To see the difference try: `Head[Unevaluated[f[x]]]` vs `Head[HoldForm[f[x]]]`

Comment: @CodeMocker While Runny's workaround indeed solves your problem, it does not give an insight on why `With` is evaluated before `Table` in one case but not in the other. For an explanation, please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To be more specific, the difference is not because of the postfix application but because of the **pure function** (the part with `#` and `&`) application:

```
Table[With[{x = i^k}, HoldForm[x]], {k, 1, 5}] (* no pure function *)
(* ==> {i, i^2, i^3, i^4, i^5} *)

With[{x = i^k}, HoldForm[x]] // (Table[#, {k, 1, 5}] &)  (* postfix pure function *)
(* ==> {i^k, i^k, i^k, i^k, i^k} *)

(Table[#, {k, 1, 5}] &) @ With[{x = i^k}, HoldForm[x]]  (* prefix pure function *)
(* ==> {i^k, i^k, i^k, i^k, i^k} *)
```

Accordingly, if you simplify your example, and put some `Print`s in it:

```
Block[{k = 1}, Print[2]; With[{x = k}, Print[1]; HoldForm@x]]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[17]:= 2
> During evaluation of In[17]:= 1
> (* ==> 1 *)
> ```

```
Block[{k = 1}, Print[2]; #] &@With[{x = k}, Print[1]; HoldForm@x]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[17]:= 1
> During evaluation of In[17]:= 2
> (* ==> k *)
> ```

As you can see, in the last case, the `With` is evaluated first, not `Block`, resulting in thus a replacement `x -> k`, so `Block` cannot replace `x` in the second step as there is no `x` anymore in the expression.

An even more simple example that shows the reversed evaluation sequence for pure function application compared to normal, nested expression evaluation:

```
(Print[2]; Print[1];)
```

> ```
> 2
> 1
> ```

```
(Print[2]; #;) & @ Print[1]; (* or:  Print[1]; // (Print[2]; #;) & *)
```

> ```
> 1
> 2
> ```

Comment: I like when you explain things with those `Prints`. It's very useful method.

Comment: @Kuba ...and a poor man's debugger :)